# Will the execution of DML statements through SQL/AUTO trace be autocommitted?

Tags: oracle, query-optimization

When we check the Autotrace or SQL trace on any sql statement, it first executes the statement.

I want to know when it executes any DML statement, it will be autocommitted or we need to commit or rollback the statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setting tracing on does not cause a commit. in sql*plus, the parameter that affects the auto-commit is "set autocommit on". So when you trace a DML statement, you have to roll it back or commit it yourself unless you've turned on autocommit.